# Merging two rows on to one in different columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Firstly sorry if this has already been answered somewhere else, I have been unable to find an answer though after days of searching.

Is there a way to merge two rows into one row using different columns.

You will see from the image below, the row is identical, other than the date and location what I am looking for is to have the details below on one row. Where the date column is displayed twice with different column names for example 'Date sent to X location' and 'Date sent to Y location'. The location would not need to be displayed if we put the correct dates in the correct columns, as they would see what the location was from the column name.

[image]

So far I use this query, and I am unsure on how to adjust it to do what I need?

```
select 
l.lot_number,
trunc(l.start_tran_date) AS "Date sent to location",
l.location_id_2 AS "Location"
FROM t_tran_log l 
WHERE  
(l.location_id_2 = 'SENTTOMAP' OR l.location_id_2 = 'WAITINGFORCOLLECTION')
;
```

This is what I would like the above result to look like:

[image]

Comment: Please post some sample data, simplified query, needed result; you can start looking at how to build a [mcve]

Comment: Hopefully that helps. - thanks

Comment: you could always achieve this by creating some views and joining these together. i.e. Create a "WaitingForCollection" view which has a column with a heading "Waiting For Collection" that displays the "Date Sent To Location" and a similar view for "Sent To Map". Join these together by the LP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only a single date to a location for a given lot, could try something like this:

```
SELECT lot_number
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN location_id = 'WAITINGFORCOLLECTION' THEN start_tran_date) ELSE NULL END) AS "Date waiting for collection"
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN location_id = 'SENTTOMAP'            THEN start_tran_date) ELSE NULL END) AS "Date sent to map"
  FROM t_tran_log
  GROUP BY lot_number
```

The aggregate function (`MAX`) will skip the `NULL` column values leaving the single value for the location.

Answer (score 1):

This would be my approach:

1- Create a test table

```
    create table MESSYLOG 
(
lotn varchar(20),
datesent date,
location varchar(20)
);


insert into messylog values ('abc', '06-JUN-16', 'waiting');
insert into messylog values ('abc', '07-JUN-16', 'sent');
insert into messylog values ('def', '08-JUN-16', 'waiting');
insert into messylog values ('def', '10-JUN-16', 'sent');

--select * from MESSYLOG
```

2- Write 2 subqueries

```
select t1.lotn,t2.DateWait, t1.DateSentmap, 
from
(
select e.lotn, e.datesent as DateSentmap
from messylog e
where e.location = 'sent'
) t1
JOIN 
 (
  select m.lotn,  m.datesent as DateWait 
from messylog m
where m.location = 'waiting'
)t2
on t1.lotn = t2.lotn
```

3-Resultset

```
        LOTN  DATEWAIT  DATESENTMAP
        abc  06-JUN-16  07-JUN-16
        def  08-JUN-16  10-JUN-16
```